# Find the solution of the following initial value problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find the solution of the following initial value problem y′′′−4y′′−5y′=9+5x with y(0)=0

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. $\lambda^3-4\lambda^2-5\lambda=0\Rightarrow \lambda_1=0;\lambda_2=-1;\lambda_3=5\Rightarrow y_h=c_1+c_2e^{-x}+c_3e^{5x}$
2. $y_p=a+bx+cx^2;y_p'=b+2cx;y_p''=2c\Rightarrow -4c-5b-5cx=9+5x\Rightarrow c=-\frac{1}{2};b=-1;a=0\Rightarrow y_p=-\frac{x^2}{2}-x$
3. $y(0)=0\Rightarrow c_1=0$